# What is the R equivalent of the solve_ivp() function in Python?

Tags: python, r, scipy, ode, runge-kutta

I am translating some code from Python to R, and am finding it hard to find the corresponding functions in each. In this particular case, the code I'm having trouble with is:

```
x_sol_best = solve_ivp(
                    fun=model_covid,
                    y0=x_0_cases,
                    t_span=[t_predictions[0], t_predictions[-1]],
                    t_eval=t_predictions,
                    args=tuple(optimal_params),
                ).y
```

From the `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp), I see that the default integration method used  in this function is : **‘RK45’ (default)**: Explicit Runge-Kutta method of order 5(4)

What packages / functions in R would be equivalent to this?

From the R [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/deSolve/man/rkMethod.html) of the `ode` function in R, I see that there are a number of RK 4(5) methods available (pasted below)  - but the Python documentation states that RK45 is order 5(4)...

Can anyone offer any clarification? TIA

```
"rk45ck"    |   Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp, order 4(5)
"rk45f" |   Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg, order 4(5); Octave: ode45, pair=1
"rk45e" |   Runge-Kutta-England, order 4(5)
"rk45dp6"   |   Dormand-Prince, order 4(5), local order 6
"rk45dp7", "ode45"  |   Dormand-Prince 4(5), local order 7
```

Comment: I guess `lsoda` in R is equivalent to `solve_ivp()` in python
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.28/topics/lsoda

Comment: I think it's more like `ode()`.  `lsoda` is one particular solver, `ode()` is a general-purpose function that allows a choice of solvers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the default solver in `solve_ivp()` is Dormand-Prince. This called `ode45` in the `ode()` function of the `deSolve` package.

```
x_sol_best = deSolve::ode(
                    y = x_0_cases,
                    times = t_predictions,
                    func = model_covid,
                    parms = c(...), # vector of parameter values
                    method = "ode45"
                )[ , -1] # drop the t column
```

Comment: thanks, Simon - is Dormand-Prince and RK45 the same thing? Or was I looking at the wrong documentation ? this link states that the default method is RK45 :https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Comment: If you click the little `[1]` in `‘RK45’ (default): Explicit Runge-Kutta method of order 5(4) [1].` it takes you to the bibliography where is says `[1] 
J. R. Dormand, P. J. Prince, “A family of embedded Runge-Kutta formulae”, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 6, No. 1, pp. 19-26, 1980.`